# How can you vertically align multi-line text within a list?

Tags: html, css

Example: [jsfiddle.net/h5sE6/](http://jsfiddle.net/h5sE6)

css:

```
ul {
    float: left;
    margin-right:20px;
}
ul li {
    height: 3em;
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;
    width:200px;
}
```

html:

```
<ul>
    <li> Some text</li>
    <li>Some text<br />some more text</li>
    <li>some test text3</li>
    <li>even more text<br />and more</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li> Some text</li>
    <li>Some text<br />some more text</li>
    <li>some test text</li>
    <li>even more text<br />and more</li>
</ul>
```

This is trivial with vertically aligning text and making the height equal to the line-height if you have one line only but any more than that, things look really screwy.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do it with a helper `:before` element and by adding a nested `<span>`:

```
ul li span {
    display: inline-block;  
    vertical-align: middle;     
}

ul li:before{
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;       
}
```

Here's [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h5sE6/5/) of it in action.

This works because two inline-block elements will vertically align with each other.  The `:before` rule creates an inline-block element that is the same height as its parent, which the variable height `<span>` can vertically align with.

For a complete explanation of how it works, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273338/how-to-properly-vertically-align-an-image/7310398#7310398) about vertically aligning images.

Comment: The li before eliminates the bullet beside the <li> point.  I found it works better if I skip that selector, and use vertical-align:top in the ul li span selector.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by adding a `span` to your markup and then using `display:table` etc in your css:

```
<ul>
    <li><span>Some text</span></li>
    <li><span>Some text<br />some more text</span></li>
    <li><span>some test text</span></li>
    <li><span>even more text<br />and more</span></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
    display: table;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

ul li {
    height: 3em;
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;
    display: table-row;
}

ul li span{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/nePt6/

Comment: This solution works very well also and is very intuitive.  The only hiccup I had with this was it caused a couple of odd visual nuances when working in tandem with some additional CSS3 styling.