# Vertical align multiple lines of li

Tags: css

This is what I'm trying to accomplish. I have a unordened list as a horizontal menu.
The `<li>` should be vertical aligned in the middle, like this:

```
 _______________________________________
|                                       |
|                                       |
|   [____]   [____]   [____]   [____]   |
|                                       |
|_______________________________________|
```

No problem so far, using `vertical-align: middle` and a `line-height`. The challenge is that I want to be able to have two lines, and have them aligned in the middle aswell, like this:

```
 _______________________________________
|                                       |
|   [____]   [____]   [____]   [____]   |
|                                       |
|       [____]    [____]    [____]      |
|_______________________________________|
```

The code so far:
**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    background: lightblue;
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 100px;
}
    ul li {
        display: inline;
    }
        ul li a {
            padding: 5px 15px;
            margin: 0 10px;
            background: lightgreen;
        }
```

I already found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717378/how-can-you-vertically-align-multi-line-text-within-a-list) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717378/how-can-you-vertically-align-multi-line-text-within-a-list), but that doesn't help me either.

I created a [single line JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WFXUp/) and a [multi line JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WFXUp/1/).

Comment: Being rather old-fashioned, I think I would just use a table...

Comment: The number of items is dynamic, so that won't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use a wrapper element, say a `<nav>` element, and ypu can do without IE7 and earlier support, maybe this will work for you: http://jsfiddle.net/LZfVY/1/

```
nav {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    background: lightblue;
    line-height: 100px;
    font-size:0;
    text-align: center;
}

ul {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: lightblue;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 2.2;
    font-size:16px;
}
ul li {
    display: inline;
}

ul li a {
    padding: 5px 15px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    background: lightgreen;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think all you needed to do was set the height of the UL to auto.

```
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 500px;
    height: auto;
    background: lightblue;
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 100px;
}
```

Take a look at [the JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LZfVY/) and see if that does what you were looking to do.

Comment: The `ul` has a fixed height (100px)... otherwise it would work.

Comment: Do you know that you have two lines inside the UL?  If that's the case, you could set the line-height to 50px.

Comment: I want to be able to have 1 line *or* 2 lines, sorry if my startpost wasn't clear.

Comment: You might want to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708054/center-ul-li-into-div

Answer (score 0):

Add `display:table-cell;` to the ul style.  Then adjust the line height as needed for proper spacing of the double line.